# sharing resharper & stylecop settings with team in solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, resharper, stylecop

I have a team of 5 developers which I work with and within the team we all use Resharper and Stylecop to assist with out development. We develop .net applications in C# using visual studio and use TFS for source control.

Each developer has a resharper and stylecop settings file on their PC which they develop against.

However having a settings file per PC leads to inconsistencies. So we would like to set it up so we have a settings file for resharper and stylecop per solution source controlled with the solution. So when a developer opens the solution, the associated settings files are used rather than a local version.

Could someone assist me in how this may be set up as I expect it is fairly common practice. I have used google to research this but I have not got any clear instructions to achieve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [http://geekswithblogs.net/alternativedotnet/archive/2008/10/20/125936.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20190923144506/http://geekswithblogs.net/alternativedotnet/archive/2008/10/20/125936.aspx) for details on how to share things like code style with the rest of the team.

Check out [http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20StyleCop%20Settings%20Across%20Projects&referringTitle=Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226050747/http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20StyleCop%20Settings%20Across%20Projects&referringTitle=Documentation) for details on how to share stylecop settings with a team.

Comment: Both links are down.

Comment: You're right, they work now. Seemed to be temporary.

Comment: Both links down for me on 2016-11-29.

Comment: Sorry, for the delay in updating the links, problem with DNS.

Comment: Second link is not active today.

Answer (score 1):

This link contains more information about the R# settings management.
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Sharing_Configuration_Options.html

This looks interesting also. But I am not sure if this still works with 7.1.
http://rsm.codeplex.com/ (resharper settings manager)